# Android Nawigation Drawer with menu as Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, navigation-drawer

In common cases all apps with Nawigation Drawer from support v4 in android has FrameLayout for containgn stuff and ListView but I need to do it in different wat instead ListView put there a Fragment, does anyyone did something like this?

Any advices will be helpfull for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All methods of `NavigationDrawer` are using `drawerView` variable of type `View`. It means you can use any subclass of `View`, not only `ListView`, so you can take, for example, another `FrameLayout` as container for you `Fragments` and work directly with it.

Comment: I have checked once again and look that there is nothing because cursor size is 0 so that's the main reason why data is invisible but yes your answer is correct.